# Auto-expand self in PyCharm debugger

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm using PyCharm for my Python development. When I'm using the debugger, I always need to look at the member variables of the class I'm debugging, so I always need to expand `self` in the variables pane.

Is there a way for this to happen automatically when the debugger launches?

Comment: I believe there's no such possibility, but feel free to create a feature request in PyCharms' bug tracker: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/PY